# How many sub-square matrices does a square matrix have and is there a simple formula for it?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, determinant, sums-of-squares

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $M$. I want to find the determinant for ALL sub-square matrices of $M$. There may be a better way but my method is to find all sub-square matrices and check them individually.

1. How many **sub-square matrices** does a square matrix have and is there a simple formula for it?

The other problem is, after checking several videos I am not sure what counts as a sub-square matrix. I thought I could use the formula for the sum of squares, i.e.
$$S(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

But this gives sixteen $(1 \times 1)$ matrices, nine $(2 \times 2)$ matrices, four $(3 \times 3)$ matrices and one $(4 \times 4)$ matrices, i.e. a total of $30$ sub-square matrices.

\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}

But, for example, I can find thirty-six $(2 \times 2)$ matrices by observation, i.e. six for any pair of rows. For example, the first two rows give:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
If I do the same for rows $1$ and $3$, $1$ and $4$, $2$ and $3$, $2$ and $4$, and $3$ and $4$, I get thirty-six sub-square matrices by considering only $(2 \times 2)$ matrices. So now I am wondering if my way of counting sub-square matrices is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: You just figured out that you miscounted the number of $2 \times 2$ submatrices by showing how to count them all by choosing $2$ rows and $3$ columns.  That kind of argument will count the square submatrices of any size. Then sum the counts. I don't know whether that sum has a nice closed form, but you could edit to make _that_ your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you admit the zero-by-zero matrix as a square submatrix, then the number
of square submatrices is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2.$$
This can be written as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom n{n-k}$$
which can be recognised as the coefficient of $t^n$ in $(1+t)^n(1+t)^n$
etc.

Comment: So by your formula I should find $1^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + 4^2 + 1^2 = 70$ sub-square matrices from a $4 \times 4$ matrix? This is with $k = 0, 1,2,3,4$, respectively. Well, the $0$-by-$0$, $1$-by-$1$ and $4$-by-$4$ matrices are easy enough to spot. And I have already found the thirty-six $2$-by-$2$ matrices ... so just the sixteen $3$-by-$3$ matrices then? I shall keep trying, at least know how many I need to find. Many thanks. And is there some easy way to check if the determinants of all $70$ sub-matrices are singular?

Comment: $1^2+\cdots+1^2=70$, not $81$. You get the three-by-three submatrices by deleting one row and one column of your original matrix.

Comment: Yes indeed. I thought I had corrected it in time! This is my seeing $1^2$ as $12$. So is there a way to check if all sub-square matrices have non-zero determinants?

Comment: @RedBook1 you could always just compute them all...

Comment: Yes I could but I am not a programmer and some of the matrices I shall be looking at will be much larger. Rgds.

Answer (score 0):

There’s 9 2x2 matrices if you only count ones that are touching. 3 for each row.

2 3 _ 3 1 _ 1 1 _ 1 2 _ 2 3 _ 3 1 _ 1 1 _ 1 2 _ 2 3
     1 2 _ 2 3 _ 3 1 _ 1 1 _ 1 2 _ 2 3 _ 3 1 _ 1 1 _ 1 2

Comment: How do you add matrices?